# reactQuery pass state isLoading to button when refetch

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I try to pass isLoading state to button prop when click button which trigger refetch function from useQuery, and it doesn't work (maybe because it re-render component and when component render isLoading is false). I wonder how i can make it works?

```
const MainPage: React.FC = () => {

    const {data, isLoading,  error, refetch} = useQuery<any>(
        ["getCity"],
        () => fetchCities(),
        {
                enabled: false,
            }
        )

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(data)}
            </div>
            <Button
                    loading={isLoading} //  always false. Need to be true when start refetch and false by the end refetch
                    label="get_cities"
                    onClick={() => refetch()}
            >

            </Button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default MainPage;
```

Comment: Is it false, when you try load the data for the first time as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isLoading` will become `true` only when query has ***no data*** and is currently fetching while `isFetching` will become `true` if the query is fetching at any time (including background refetching).

In your case, just use `isFetching` instead of `isLoading`

```
const { isLoading, isFetching } = useQuery(...);

if(isLoading){
    return <div>Loading cities...</div>
}

return <Button
    loading={isFetching}
    label="get_cities"
    onClick={() => refetch()}
>
```